# NameError: name 'cas_conn' is not defined in sasoptpy

Tags: python, optimization

I'm trying to learn sasoptpy. I have installed it in my python 3.6 after that I'm trying to execute the examples 
[given here](https://sassoftware.github.io/sasoptpy/examples/nonlinear_1.html)

Copied the complete code from here.If you want to check my code then please refer this link  but while I'm running it,I'm getting error message as `NameError: name 'cas_conn' is not defined`  Can you suggest me what should I do to avoid this error

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

`cas_conn` parameter in that example represents an active CAS (SAS Viya) connection.
SAS Viya is SAS' cloud computing solution. To be able to solve problems with sasoptpy, you will need to have a running server.

See https://sassoftware.github.io/sasoptpy/getting-started.html#creating-a-session for more information about creating a session.

If you have access to a CAS server, try the following:

```
from swat import CAS
cas_conn = CAS(your_cas_server, your_cas_port)
test(cass_conn)
```